# How to calculate SHA from a string with the Github api in python?

Tags: python, git, github-api

I want to update a file with the Github API and commit it into a branch. I have troubles creating the commit. The SHA does not match the expected one.

```
{
    'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.7/v3/repos/contents/',
    'message': 'pom.xml does not match de42fdd980f9b8067a2af982de46b8d5547e4597'
}
```

I do the following:

```
import hashlib
myfile = "new content of my README"
resulting_file = base64.b64encode(bytes(myfile, "utf-8"))
file_as_str = str(resulting_file.decode('utf-8'))
sha = hashlib.sha1(file_as_str.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

url = 'https://someurl.com/someproject/contents/README.md?access_token=' + access_token
data = '{"message": "bla bla", "content": "'+file_as_str+'", "sha": "'+sha+'", "branch": "'+branch+'"}'
response = requests.put(url, data=data)
```

I would not like to use a lib to do this to better understand what is happening. probably the SHA is not generated properly, but I cannot identify why. Could someone help?

Comment: are you sure you need to checksum the base64 encoded version of the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the SHA for the new file. Instead you must supply the  SHA of the file that is being *replaced*. You can obtain that by performing a [get contents](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.7/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) on the file using `requests.get()`:

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/someowner/someproject/contents/pom.xml'
r = requests.get(url)
sha = r.json()['sha']
```

Then use the value of `sha` in the `PUT` request to update the file:

```
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    content = str(base64.b64encode(f.read()), encoding='utf8')
    data = {'message': 'bla bla', 'content': content, 'sha': sha, 'branch': branch}
    r = requests.put(url, json=data)
```

Comment: Thx, for the answer. Now I have 2 different interpretation of the api. None of them seem to work. When I get the SHA as you showed, I still get an error.

Comment: One thing to be aware of when using grabbing the SHA via the file contents API is that the API only works for files up to one megabyte in size, so will fail if the file is larger than that. I expect the `pom.xml` in the original question is smaller than this, but generalising to other files might be problematic.

Comment: @PaulFournel: What error do you get? I can assure you that you must use the sha of the file that is being replaced, not the sha of the new content.  I didn't show it, but you also need to add authentication to the `put` request - either in the HTTP header, or in the query string.

Comment: @PaulFournel:  Also check that you have set the appropriate permissions for the personal access token that you are using for the update request. You need to have at least "Access public repositories " in the "repo" scope enabled.

Comment: I finally got it working. I was using the SHA from master and trying to push to a branch... Could not work. It works now.

Comment: @PaulFournel: ok, that would explain it.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub calculates hashes as followes:

```
sha1("blob " + filesize + "\0" + data)
```

so use this code:

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as file_for_hash:
    data = file_for_hash.read()
    filesize = len(data)
sha = hashlib.sha1("blob " + filesize + "\0" + data).hexdigest()
```

Comment: This appears to only be true for files smaller than 1MB. For larger files this does not match